# Todo notes cropped (potentially with fullpage package)

Tags: todonotes, fullpage

I find that my todo notes are cropped:

[image: cropped \todo note]

This seems to be the case no matter where I put the note. I think the problem might be the `fullpage` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm, todonotes, color, amsfonts, hyperref, amssymb, tipa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\todo{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.} consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Please help :)

The same problem arises with the following code and resolves when `fullpage` is removed:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{amsart}
 \usepackage{fullpage}
 \usepackage{todonotes}

 \begin{document}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\todo{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.} consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: `fullpage` sets the margins width to be 1in by default. Use something like `\usepackage[textwidth=0.75in]{todonotes}` instead?

Comment: Nah, that didn't work, @Troy.

Comment: Did you load `todonotes` on its own, with this option, instead of in a bundle as in your sample code?

Comment: Yes, @erreka; I've edited the question.

Comment: Shaun, I've tried it here and Troy's suggestion works perfectly. In what sense did it not work for you?

Comment: It simply produced the same problem, @gusbrs. I don't know why.

Comment: In the new code you provided, what happens if you substitute `\usepackage{todonotes}` with `\usepackage[textwidth=0.75in]{todonotes}` and rebuild your document? (It is supposed to work, and it works for me).

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it, @gusbrs; it works now but it didn't the first time I tried it.

Comment: Imho, that is the best way to do this, with the use of the available package option. Now you opened the bounty, you got some other answers too, which present other possibilities. But, perhaps @Troy may want to step in too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value to change is `textwidth`, and the manual points out that you need to adjust `\marginparwidth`, so

```
\usepackage[textwidth=0.7in]{todonotes}
```

Equivalently,

```
\usepackage{todonotes}
\setlength\marginparwidth{0.7in}
```

should do the job.

Comment: From the documentation: "`textsize=value` sets the default text size of the inserted todonotes to the given value. Value is the ”name” of the used font size, eg. if the desired fontsize is `\tiny` use `textsize=tiny`. The default value is  `textsize=normalsize`."

Comment: you're right: I messed up the name of the key while typing. thanks.

Comment: If so, you are essentially employing Troy's suggestion. The call to `\setlenght\marginparwidth` is, as far as I can tell, redundant there.

Comment: @gusbrs section `1.6.7 Reduce number of warnings` of the manual recommends it. In fact, what I think the op was doing wrong was the call to `todonotes`. I only pointed out the right way to do it, the same as you say in your comment above.

Comment: Well, `\setlenght\marginparwidth` seems to be doing something: it works but `\usepackage[textwidth=0.7in]{todonotes}` does not.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use package `fullpage`. Set the margin with `geometry`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[margin=2cm,rmargin=5mm,includemp]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm, todonotes, color}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\todo{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.} consectetur 
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same setting as `fullpage`:

```
 \usepackage[margin=1in,marginpar=0.75in]{geometry}
```

or with `fullpage`

```
 \usepackage{fullpage}
 \setlength\marginparwidth{0.75in}
```

Comment: I'd rather use `fullpage`: I like the proportions.

Comment: It is no problem to set the same margins with geometry. `fullpage` doesn't set the margin text width, which looks like a bug. See edited answer for values just like the one from `fullpage`

Comment: Don't throw 1k of code to a problem you can solve with 1 line.

Comment: `fullpage` is 3kb; `geometry` is 42kb.

Comment: @erreka but fullpage is so minimal that someone could almost call it bugged. Obv it's not bugged, simply it doesn't handle the margins.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not so much a problem of todonotes. Rather, even a simple `\marginpar` would get cropped, and todonotes happens to use `\marginpar`.  To avoid the cropping, you can make `\marginparwidth` smaller. (IMHO fullpage should do that automatically.)

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{amsart}
 \usepackage{fullpage}
 \usepackage{todonotes}
 \makeatletter
 \setlength\marginparwidth{\FP@margin}
 \addtolength\marginparwidth{-4mm}
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\todo{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua.} consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliqua. \marginpar{xyz abc def gh }

 \end{document}
```

Comment: @erreka Yes, I said it should. It defines its own margin width, `\FP@margin`, but doesn't adjust `marginparwidth`. So ordinary  `\marginpars` get also cropped.